# Azure B2C - custom password policy per customer

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are looking to implement an identity management solution for a number of customers using Azure B2C. I created a proof of concept and have that currently set up.

We are now hoping to implement a custom administrator portal, that will allow each of our customers to log in and alter their own password policies. Specifically, complexity, attempts before lockout, lockout time, and token lifetime.

Complexity and token lifetime are currently set via B2C Custom Policies, and I understand attempts before lockout and lockout time are a per tenant setting. We have a single B2C tenant at the moment segregating customers by security group but are not opposed to creating a tenant per customer if that would work better.

I am just seeking some advice on the best way to approach this, we maybe need to implement each of these features ourselves using the Graph API, although I am struggling to find endpoints for all of the requirements.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Token timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) etc. are configured per custom policy.

[Session timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) etc. are configured per relying party.

Smart lockouts are per tenant.

I don't think there are APIs for all of these.

Having one tenant would mean having different sets of policies, one set for each customer.

Different tenants sound the way to go.

Ultimately, these are text files.

You could have a portal that takes the parameters, alters the text files, and then uploads them.

There are [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta) to upload, delete, etc., custom policies.